# Grafana alerts high and low water marks

Tags: grafana-alerts

I have an alert for when a value is exceeded, and get the notifications when the alert has been cleared.  So far, so good.

What I am looking for is a way to have the clear alert set to a lower value.  For example if my threshold is 80%, I want the alert sent at 80%, but not cleared until 70%, so I do not get excessive noise at: 80%, 79%, 81%, 78%, ..., 70%, 71%, ....  I should get one alert for exceeding 80% and one alert for clearing the threshold.

This is commonly know as high water and low water marks.  (Think sump pumps, where you do not want the motor to repeatedly turn on and off.)